# Error: TimeoutException Future not completed And TypeError: T.as is not a function at _Future.new.[_setValue]

Tags: firebase-storage, flutter-web

I got this error while dealing with Flutter web and Firebase Storage:

> Error: TimeoutException after 0:00:05.000000: Future not completed
>       at Object.createErrorWithStack (http://localhost:65534/dart_sdk.js:4478:12)
>       at Object._rethrow (http://localhost:65534/dart_sdk.js:37394:16)
>       at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:65534/dart_sdk.js:37388:13)

Then followed by this error (always in pairs)

> TypeError: T.as is not a function
>       at _Future.new.[_setValue] (http://localhost:60098/dart_sdk.js:32317:11)
>       at Function._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:60098/dart_sdk.js:32660:30)
>       at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:60098/dart_sdk.js:32357:27)
>       at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:60098/dart_sdk.js:37220:13)
>       at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:60098/dart_sdk.js:37226:13)
>       at http://localhost:60098/dart_sdk.js:32848:9

I have spent the whole 2 days to figure out where this comes from.

So far with the best of my knowledge it seems to come from when I upload an image to Firebase Storage:

Here is the code:

```
final uploadTask = _storageRef.child(_path).put(_file,
    fb.UploadMetadata(
        contentType: _file.type, customMetadata: customMetaData));

// Listening to the progress.
final StreamSubscription<fb.UploadTaskSnapshot> stream =
    uploadTask.onStateChanged.listen((event) => event);

stream.onDone(() {
  uploadTask.cancel();
  stream.cancel();
});
```

And just in case someone asks, here's my `flutter doctor -v`

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel dev, 1.20.0-0.0.pre, on Mac OS X 10.15.5 01, locale
    en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.20.0-0.0.pre at /Applications/flutter
    • Framework revision d9653445f4 (7 days ago), 2020-06-09 18:43:03 -0400
    • Engine revision e8c13aa012
    • Dart version 2.9.0 (build 2.9.0-14.0.dev 5c1376615e)
    • Pub download mirror https://pub.flutter-io.cn
    • Flutter download mirror https://storage.flutter-io.cn


[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Applications/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Applications/Android/sdk
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android
      Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.4.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.4.1, Build version 11E503a
    • CocoaPods version 1.9.1

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 47.0.2-dev.2
    • Dart plugin version 193.7361
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.46.0)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.11.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • Web Server • web-server • web-javascript • Flutter Tools
    • Chrome     • chrome     • web-javascript • Google Chrome 83.0.4103.106

• No issues found!
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: i'm having the same error. did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this issue too; it seems to be caused by some quirk in the JS-interop feature of dart (I created an issue in dart-lang/sdk attempting to get some clarification!)

The root cause of this particular problem was an issue with the internal implementation of the `onStateChanged` Stream in the UploadTask class, [here](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firebase-dart/pull/345/files#diff-a956a0555d5d522fffe19884b15b5f4ed920c93fa94898b2e08bc6a214daa96d).

The original code was defining the onCompletion callback of the UploadTask as:

```dart
var onCompletion = allowInterop(() => _changeController.close());
```

But whatever `.close()` was returning was [unexpected in the js-interop layer](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firebase-dart/blob/master/lib/src/interop/storage_interop.dart#L100-L101) and causing this crash, so I replaced it by:

```dart
var onCompletion = allowInterop(() {
  _changeController.close();
});
```

Which did the trick, at least on the firebase_storage_web plugin I'm working on!

**The fix has been [published as `firebase:^7.3.1`](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase/changelog#731)**

*PS: Looking at the `package:firebase` code, I bet the OP wouldn't have any issues if they used `uploadTask.future`, instead of `uploadTask.onStateChanged`, but of course you can't have upload progress then*. [Docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase/7.3.0/firebase/UploadTask-class.html#instance-properties).